# How can I insert a file name into a VLOOKUP function

Tags: vba, excel, filepath, vlookup

I'm almost finished with this macro that would allow the user to select a file path and then it would perform a `vlookup` from the selected file in the other file. My code so far looks like:

```
Sub SelectFile()
Dim x As String
Dim lNewBracketLocation As Long

x = Application.GetOpenFilename()

MsgBox "You selected " & x
'Find the last instance in the string of the path separator "\"
lNewBracketLocation = InStrRev(x, Application.PathSeparator)
'Edit the string to suit the VLOOKUP formula - insert "["
x = Left$(x, lNewBracketLocation) & "[" & Right$(x, Len(x) - lNewBracketLocation)

Range("AA2").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1]C23&R[-1]C24,'" & x & "]Access'!C3:C27,6,0)"
```

After the file is selected, the VLOOKUP will need to look like this:

> =VLOOKUP($W2&$X2,'S:\Finance Forecast\Inventory Folders\2015\LW[08-AUG-Access Export.xlsx]Access'!$C:$AA,6,FALSE)

When I run the macro, I keep getting Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error on the VLOOKUP formula line
I am new to VBA and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Luke

Comment: Looks like you're missing another backslash before the file name?

Comment: mistype, sorry. It should output this:
=VLOOKUP($W2&$X2,'S:\Finance Forecast\Inventory Folders\2015\LW\ [08-AUG-Access Export.xlsx]Access'!$C:$AA,6,FALSE)
(space intentional for demo purposes)

Comment: Does that formula work when you manually type it into a cell (ie: is there a spelling mistake / denied access to that folder)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got one too many Cs in the formula. It should be:

```
Range("AA2").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(R[-1]C23&R[-1]C24,'" & x & "]Access'!C3:C27,6,0)"
```

rather than

```
Range("AA2").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1]C23&R[-1]C24,'" & x & "]Access'!C3:C27,6,0)"
```

Comment: Thanks Rory, everything checks out now.